# How to reference an unnumbered section by writing a number?

Tags: cross-referencing

I have an appendix with sections, e.g. `section*{Appendix 1: Measurment of X.Y.}`. I have set a label with `\label{appendix:1}`. Now if I reference that appendix via `\ref{appendix:1}` I get the number of the last numbered chapter before the appendix. This is because my appendix is also an unnumbered chapter. In my text I want the number of the appendix (each section* is a new appendix here) to be shown, like "in appendix 3 you can see...". How can I do that?

EDIT:
Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[
    paper=a4,               
    twoside=true,           
    open=right,             
    fontsize=12pt,              
    parskip,                
    headsepline,            
    cleardoublepage=empty,  
    ]{scrbook}              

\usepackage{scrpage2}       
\pagestyle{scrheadings}     
\automark[section]{chapter}
\clearscrheadings           
\ihead{}                    
\chead{}                    
\ohead{\headmark}           
\ifoot{}                    
\cfoot{}                    
\clearscrplain 
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\setlength{\headheight}{1.1\baselineskip}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage[
    backend=bibtex,
    ]{biblatex}

\usepackage[pdftex,
            colorlinks,
            linkcolor = black]{hyperref}

\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix} 

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents    

\chapter{Just a chapter}
Blabla
\chapter{Just another chapter}
Bla, bla, see appendix \ref{appendix:1}. Here should be a 1 for the first appendix and not the 2 for the last numbered chapter.


\chapter*{Appendix}

\begin{appendix}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{Anhang \arabic{section}:}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}

\newpage
\section*{Appendix 1: Measurement X.Y.} \label{appendix:1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix 1: Measurement X.Y.}
\chaptermark{Appendix}
\end{appendix}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course you do, how are you going to refer with a number to something without a number? But since you put a number in the title manually, i think you really should redefine your section commands in the appendix.

Comment: If you need help with that, provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: I have added an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is a stick to `\section*`, then slightly redefining the `\section*` command helps, but in my this case it will always add a TOC entry automatically.

I dropped the `\begin{appendix}...\end{appendix}` as it provides basically no advantages in my point of view.

The pagestyle can be changed at will.

```
\documentclass[
    paper=a4,               
    twoside=true,           
    open=right,             
    fontsize=12pt,              
    parskip,                
    headsepline,            
    cleardoublepage=empty,  
    ]{scrbook}              

%\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{scrpage2}       
\pagestyle{scrheadings}     
\automark[section]{chapter}
\clearscrheadings           
\ihead{}                    
\chead{}                    
\ohead{\headmark}           
\ifoot{}                    
\cfoot{}                    
\clearscrplain 
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\setlength{\headheight}{1.1\baselineskip}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage[
    backend=bibtex,
    ]{biblatex}

\usepackage[pdftex,
            colorlinks,
            linkcolor = black]{hyperref}

\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix} 

\newcounter{starredsection}[chapter]


\makeatletter
\let\LaTeXStandardsection\section
\newcommand{\unstarred@@section@@noopt}[1]{%
  \unstarred@@section@@opt[#1]{#1}%
}%

\newcommand{\unstarred@@section@@opt}[2][]{%
  \LaTeXStandardsection[#1]{#2}%
}%

\newcommand{\unstarredsection}{%
\@ifnextchar[{\unstarred@@section@@opt}{\unstarred@@section@@noopt}%
}%

\newcommand{\starredsection}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{starredsection}%
\LaTeXStandardsection*{#1}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}#1}%
}%

\renewcommand{\section}{%
\@ifstar{\starredsection}{\unstarredsection}%
}%




\begin{document}

\tableofcontents    

\chapter{Just a chapter}
Blabla
\chapter{Just another chapter}
Bla, bla, see appendix \ref{appendix:1}. Here should be a 1 for the first appendix and not the 2 for the last numbered chapter. But here will be 2 because, it's a reference to appendix \ref{appendix:2}%


\pagestyle{plain}
\clearscrheadings
\clearscrplain
\pagestyle{scrheadings}%
\lehead{\appendixname~\thestarredsection}

\chapter*{\appendixname}


%\begin{appendix}
%\chaptermark{Appendix}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{Anhang \arabic{section}:}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}

%\newpage
\section*{Appendix 1: Measurement X.Y.} \label{appendix:1}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix 1: Measurement X.Y.}
%\end{appendix}

\blindtext

\section*{Appendix 2: Measurement Y.Z } \label{appendix:2}

\blindtext[2]


\end{document}
```

Comment: It works, thank you. Is there a tool for writing that code, or where do the % at the end of each row come from? I am curious how I could learn such coding.

Comment: If there is a tool, I don't know of it and the `%` at the end prevents spurious white space after a command row etc. ended (or within some argument to a command).

Comment: So it looks like I'd have to deeply dive into the manuals to be able to write such code on my own. Thank you :)

Comment: @user2366975: Not necessarily: I can readily explain it to you, but to be honest, I have not written such code one year before ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You should use `\section` and not `\section*`. Here's a possible solution, which assumes you don't have `\subsection` commands in the appendices. If you have, it is not difficult, just a little more complicated, to arrange for them.

```
\documentclass[
  paper=a4,               
  twoside=true,           
  open=right,             
  fontsize=12pt,              
  parskip,                
  headsepline,            
  cleardoublepage=empty,  
]{scrbook}              

\usepackage{scrpage2}       
\pagestyle{scrheadings}     
\automark[section]{chapter}
\clearscrheadings           
\ihead{}                    
\chead{}                    
\ohead{\headmark}           
\ifoot{}                    
\cfoot{}                    
\clearscrplain 
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\setlength{\headheight}{1.1\baselineskip}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage[
  backend=bibtex,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage[
  colorlinks,
  linkcolor = black
]{hyperref}

\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix} 

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents    

\chapter{Just a chapter}
Blabla

\chapter{Just another chapter}

Bla, bla, see appendix \ref{appendix:1}. Here should be a 1 for the first appendix 
and not the 2 for the last numbered chapter.


\chapter*{Appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}
\chaptermark{Appendix}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\begin{appendix}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{Appendix \csname the#1\endcsname: }
\makeatother

\section{Measurement X.Y.} \label{appendix:1}

\end{appendix}

\end{document}
```

### The reference

[image]

### The appendix

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If think this is the wrong way to go. Your different appenices
are supposed to have the same level as the rest of the document,
that is *chapter*. So the cleanest solution would be to use
*part* to denote your appendix (if you really want to do so). As
the numbering scheme changes from `arabic` to `Alph` the reader
expects something to happen there. No need for a big *hey, look
everybody, the appendix starts here*.

Have a look at the two solutions below, they don't require any
funmbling around.

After all, this is more a question of style than the LaTeX
implementation.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Polishing eggs}
See appendix \ref{app:measurement} for further information.
Especially \ref{app:measurement:xy}
\appendix
%\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\appendixname}%
%This would be the clean solution
\chapter{Measurements}
\label{app:measurement}
\section{LASER things}
\label{app:measurement:xy}
\section{Plasma stuff}
\chapter{Third party data}
\end{document}
```

And here is the output for the table of contents:
[image]

Another solution, but not as clean as the one before. But still,
here we go:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Polishing eggs}
See appendix \ref{app:measurement:xy} for further information.
\appendix
\addchap{Appendix}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\section{Measurement LASER things} 
\label{app:measurement:xy}
\section{Measurement Plasma stuff}
\end{document}
```